# Google cloud platform gcp delete snapshot 10 days older using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, snapshot

I want to delete the snapshot which is 10 days older in GCP using python. I tried using the below program using filter expression, but unfortunately i faced  below errors

```
from datetime import datetime
from googleapiclient import discovery
import google.oauth2.credentials
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import sys
def get_disks(project,zone):
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(r"D:\Users\ganeshb\Desktop\Json\auth.json",
                                                                   scopes='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute')
    service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1',credentials=credentials)
    
    request = service.snapshots().list(project='xxxx',FILTER="creationTimestamp<'2021-05-31'")
    response = request.execute()
    print (response)
output = get_disks("xxxxxxxx", "europe-west1-b")
```

Comment: What is the **error**?

Comment: For the `scope`, I recommend using `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`. Actual permissions should be determined by the roles assigned to the identity.

Comment: Can you share the errors that you have?

Comment: returned "Invalid value for field 'filter': 'creationTimestamp = >'2021-06-01''. Invalid list filter expression.". Details: "[{'message': "Invalid value for field 'filter': 'creationTimestamp = 
>'2021-06-01''. Invalid list filter expression.", 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalid'}]">

Comment: HI Team , My idea is first I want to filter the creation of  timestamp snapshot for last 5 days . I would like to delete the rest of snapshot files

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a known Google Cloud bug.

Please read these issue trackers: [132365111](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132365111) and [132676194](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132676194)

**Solution:**

Remove the filter statement and process the returned results:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import parser

request = service.snapshots().list(project=project)

response = request.execute()

# Watch for timezone issues here!
filter_date = '2021-05-31'

d1 = parser.parse(filter_date)

for item in response['items']:
    d2 = datetime.fromisoformat(item['creationTimestamp'])

    if d2.timestamp() < d1.timestamp():
        # Process the result here. This is a print statement stub.
        print("{} {}".format(item['name'], item['creationTimestamp']))
```

Comment: Hello sir, Thanks for your reply..... The below script suits for 31-may-2021....how can i run this daily??? By taking system date?

Comment: @balaganesh Create a new question.

Comment: How can i use the filer_date with system date  specific to run the script daily  ?

Comment: @balaganesh - your original question has been answered. Running scripts on a schedule is a different question, so create a new question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Executed the below python it doesn't any results ,,,,,i want to delete the snapshots which is older 10 days how to achieve this ??******************************************************************************************